# OpenGL Vertex Arrays required version

Tags: arrays, opengl, server-side, vertex

I have my program working with VBO's efficiently however it has come to my knowledge that no-one I know with the exception of 1 person has a computer that even comes close to supporting OpenGL 3.0. When they all run programs I have made all they get are flat textures that have no depth because their cards don't support VBO's nor the Shader language that I am using.

I am now coding in support for older computers (Prior OpenGL 3.0 support). I don't want to code in drawing in immediate mode unless completely necessary, so I'm reverting to Vertex Arrays.

What version of OpenGL is required to support Vertex Arrays?

I cant seem to locate this anywhere.

Extension Registry:
http://www.opengl.org/registry/

Just to clarify I am talking about Client-side vertex arrays not to be confused with server-side Vertex Array Objects (VAO's) or Vertex Buffer Objects (VBO's)

Comment: If they don't have support for buffer objects (even Intel's crappy 1.4 implementations have those), odds are good that their OpenGL implementations are also highly buggy. So supporting such cards is a... difficult prospect if you can't actually test on the hardware.

Comment: Very true. That's why this is a fall-back **only** if VBO's are not supported.

Answer (score 8):

I'll be somewhat comprehensive here.

The basic vertex array API has been core since OpenGL 1.1.

**OpenGL 1.1** introduced:

- `glDrawArrays` and `glDrawElements` (as well as `glArrayElement`, but really nobody should use that for anything *ever*) for rendering.
- `glVertexPointer`, `glTexCoordPointer`, `glNormalPointer`, and `glColorPointer` for "attributes". Note that you only get one texture coordinate pointer.

**OpenGL 1.2** introduced:

- `glDrawRangeElements`, for improved performance on some drivers. Not very useful these days, but if you're coding for old hardware, look into it.

**OpenGL 1.3** introduced:

- `glActiveTexture`, thus allowing `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS` numbers of `glTexCoordPointer`s.

**OpenGL 1.4** introduced:

- `glMultiDrawArrays` and `glMultiDrawElements`.
- `glSecondaryColorPointer` and `glFogCoordPointer`.

**OpenGL 1.5** introduced:

- Buffer objects.

**OpenGL 2.0** introduced:

- `glVertexAttribPointer` for generic shader attributes. Usable with client-side vertex arrays.

Comment: This is great! No immediate mode required after-all. If their computer doesn't support OpenGL 1.1 I'm sure they shouldn't be running the game.

Comment: this history is wonderful, ive spent all day researching the history of vertex submission in openGL and this is better than a lot of the wikipedia articles.

Answer (score 5):

The earliest mention of vertex arrays I can find in the [specifications](http://www.opengl.org/registry/#oldspecs) is [OpenGL 1.1](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec11.ps) (Section 2.8 Vertex Arrays, page 21).